Could you review my algorithm to assess its conceptual and practical validity for maintaining primal feasibility?
Problem Formulation
We aim to solve the following convex quadratic optimization problem:
Objective Function:
Minimize:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^\top Q x + q^\top x,
$$
where:

( Q ) is a positive definite matrix (( Q \succ 0 )),
( q \in \mathbb{R}^n ),
( x \in \mathbb{R}^n ) is the decision variable.

Constraints:

Box Constraints:
$$
   l_i \leq x_i \leq u_i, \quad i = 1, \dots, n,
   $$
where:

( l_i ) and ( u_i ) are the lower and upper bounds on ( x_i ).


Linear Constraint:
$$
   a^\top x \geq b,
   $$
where:

( a \in \mathbb{R}^n ) is the coefficient vector,
( b \in \mathbb{R} ) is a scalar.



Feasible Region:
The feasible region ( \mathcal{F} ) is defined as:
$$
\mathcal{F} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : l \leq x \leq u, \, a^\top x \geq b \}.
$$
Algorithm: Gradient Projection with Explicit Dual Variable Updates and Feasibility Maintenance
Inputs:

Problem parameters: ( Q, q, a, b, l, u )
Numerical tolerance ( \phi > 0 ) (a small positive constant for feasibility checks)
Convergence tolerance ( \epsilon > 0 )

Outputs:

Optimal primal solution ( x^* )
Dual variables ( \lambda^*, \gamma^+, \gamma^- )


Algorithm Steps:

Initialization:

Choose ( x_0 ) such that ( l \leq x_0 \leq u ) and ( a^\top x_0 \geq b ).
Set ( \lambda_0 \geq 0, \gamma^+_0 \geq 0, \gamma^-_0 \geq 0 ).
Set the iteration counter ( k = 0 ).


Repeat until convergence:

Compute the gradient of the objective function:
$$
  \nabla f(x_k) = 2Qx_k + q
  $$

Projection onto the tangent cone:
Solve the projection problem:
$$
  d_k = \arg \min_d \| d + \nabla f(x_k) + \lambda_k a - \gamma^-_k + \gamma^+_k \|^2,
  $$
subject to:
$$
  \begin{aligned}
  a^\top d &\geq 0, \\
  d_i &\geq 0 \quad \text{if } x_{k,i} = l_i, \\
  d_i &\leq 0 \quad \text{if } x_{k,i} = u_i.
  \end{aligned}
  $$

Compute the step size:
Compute the feasible step size ( \alpha_k ):
$$
  \alpha_k = \min \Bigg\{
  \min_{i : d_{k,i} > 0} \frac{u_i - x_{k,i}}{d_{k,i}}, \,
  \min_{i : d_{k,i} < 0} \frac{x_{k,i} - l_i}{-d_{k,i}}, \,
  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_{k,i} - b}{-\sum_{i=1}^n a_i d_{k,i}}
  \Bigg\}.
  $$
Ensure ( \alpha_k \leq \alpha_k^{\text{optimal}}, ) where:
$$
  \alpha_k^{\text{optimal}} = -\frac{x_k^\top Q d_k + q^\top d_k}{d_k^\top Q d_k}.
  $$

Update the primal variable:
$$
  x_{k+1} = x_k + \alpha_k d_k.
  $$

Check primal feasibility:
If ( x_{k+1} ) violates constraints:
$$
  l_i - \phi \leq x_{k+1,i} \leq u_i + \phi, \quad a^\top x_{k+1} \geq b - \phi,
  $$
re-project ( x_{k+1} ) onto the feasible set:
$$
  x_{k+1} = \arg \min_{x \in \mathcal{F}} \| x - x_{k+1} \|,
  $$
where ( \mathcal{F} = { x \in \mathbb{R}^n : l \leq x \leq u, , a^\top x \geq b } ).

Update the dual variables:
$$
  \lambda_{k+1} = \max(0, \lambda_k + \alpha_k (b - a^\top x_{k+1})),
  $$
$$
  \gamma^+_{k+1,i} = \max(0, \gamma^+_{k,i} + \alpha_k (x_{k+1,i} - u_i)), \quad \forall i,
  $$
$$
  \gamma^-_{k+1,i} = \max(0, \gamma^-_{k,i} + \alpha_k (l_i - x_{k+1,i})), \quad \forall i.
  $$

Check for convergence:
If:
$$
  \| d_k + \nabla f(x_k) \| < \epsilon,
  $$
and the complementary slackness conditions hold:
$$
  \lambda (b - a^\top x) = 0, \quad \gamma^+_i (x_i - u_i) = 0, \quad \gamma^-_i (l_i - x_i) = 0, \quad \forall i,
  $$
terminate with:
$$
  x^* = x_{k+1}, \quad \lambda^* = \lambda_{k+1}, \quad \gamma^+_* = \gamma^+_{k+1}, \quad \gamma^-_* = \gamma^-_{k+1}.
  $$



Increment ( k = k + 1 ) and repeat.



Tags:
convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, feasibility, kkt-conditions

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

That is a pretty big ask.

@copper.hat Thank you for your input! The question has been revised for clarity—your further feedback is welcome

As far as I see you only changed the title from asking a more specific to a vastly more general question. Honestly, this needs to be implemented to see if it works.

Thank you for pointing that out, implementation is indeed a good idea, but I’d appreciate any insights on the theoretical soundness as a first step
